# I'm replacing a motion sensor light switch.There are two switches to contol this light. I swapped wire for wire

Tags: wiring

[image][image][image] The motion sensor became defective after 10 years or more.  There are two switches to contol this light.  I swapped wire for wire - red to red, black to black, green to ground, and white to white.  Light works when on.  Doesn't work when set to auto. Sensor indicator doesn't light, except when the distant switch is turned off, but then the ceiling light doesn't come on. Should have been a two minute job.  I've been playing with this for an hour.  lol

Comment: What make and model was the old motion sensor switch, and what make and model is the replacement? Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: It looks like it's probably a setting on the new switch

Comment: Yes.  Thanks.  Old switch is a Levitron PR180.  New one is TopGreener TSOS5.  Setting dials are a bit different.

Comment: I don't think the TSOS5 is a 3-way, I don't this it will work like you want it to. https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/B1jxHAnb2pS.pdf

Comment: @Doc -- do you have your heart set on this particular sensor, or is taking it back and getting a different sensor an option?

Comment: taking it back is just an inconvenience, but definitely an option.  Actually got it delivered by Amazon Prime, but it will go back.  The old Levitron I probably got at Home Depot 20 years ago.

Comment: Doc, you might want to send that switch back. The made in china is proudly stamped on it but no UL or other third party certification meaning this switch is a code violation in quite a few countries. I would return it and get another certified product that will last for another 20 years instead of no name junk from china that doesn’t meet our code criteria.

Comment: Done.  Sent back, refund issued.  Got the right switch at HD and installed.  It is not the same as what I replaced, but works as it should.  Thanks

Comment: @EdBeal -- oddly enough, the switch the OP got is simply mismarked (listed but not labeled somehow) as looking up the file number (E468463) in UL's database gets me a valid listing entry for Topgreener that shows the TSOS5 as one of the listed models

Comment: Good to know, @ThreePhaseEel. Thanks for checking into that!

Comment: @threephaseeel, last year we put in a 200a transfer switch. I told the owner it was not listed and he said it was, the inspector would not sign off because it did not have the UL mark. I showed him the document the owner had looked up and contacted the seller (brick and mortar store) they replaced the switch as that one was built prior to them getting UL approval. I guess they shipped a bunch of the old ones but it cost the home owner about 4 extra hours to remove and replace so use caution without the mark.

Comment: Yeah @EdBeal -- the lack of a mark would be concerning for me as well, since the requirements often are not just for *listing* but *labeling* as well

Answer (score 1):

### That sensor doesn't support 3-ways, so you were correct to replace it

The Topgreener TSOS5 doesn't support 3-way operation, only single-pole use (note the lack of a traveller wire/terminal on it), so you were correct to take it back and replace it with something suited for 3-way service.  (Trying to adapt a motion-sensor to 3-way service using a relay would lead to somewhat...counterintuitive behavior, I suspect.)